# Adding a string value to the end of each value in a Numpy Array Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy, format

What would be a numpy function that goes through array `a` and then appends the `endswidth` to the end of each string in the `a` array.

Code:

```
a = np.array(["BTC", "ETH", "AUD", "DOGE"])
endswidth = "USD"
```

Expected output:

```
[BTCUSD, ETHUSD, AUDUSD, DOGE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.core.defchararray.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.add.html#numpy-core-defchararray-add):

```py
a = np.array(["BTC", "ETH", "AUD", "DOGE"])
endswidth = "USD"

print(np.core.defchararray.add(a, endswidth))
```

Prints:

```
['BTCUSD' 'ETHUSD' 'AUDUSD' 'DOGEUSD']
```

---

EDIT: To replace a string:

```py
print(np.core.defchararray.replace(a, "USD", ""))
```

---

As @hpulj stated in the comments, the short form:

```py
np.char.add(...) 
np.char.replace(...)
```

Comment: if I wanted to remove "USD" instead of the `.add` what would I use because I tried `subtract` and `remove` dont work.

Comment: `np.char.add` for short.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this brute force approach will help

```
np.array([item+endswidth for item in a])
```

Comment: For string operations this is just as good as the `np.char.add`.  `numpy` does not implement its own fast string methods.